# Spotfire TERR filter table from multi-list property control?

Tags: r, spotfire, terr

I have a TERR data function that takes an input table and outputs a duplicate of that table (pretty standard stuff). What I'm trying to do is filter it from a multi-list property control. The table.column and the property control are both dates (specifically, data.column is datetime and the property control shows as Date List). I know how to filter a viz using data limiting:

```
$map("[TestID] = Date('${pcMultiListBox}')", " or ")
```

'TestID' is the column name that I want to filter in TERR function before outputting the duplicated input table. The property control iteslf is a Data List (`1/9/2022, 1/1/2022, 1/5/2022` ) but when I input it via input parameters in the TERR function and then output it as a value then it displays as a long string. I'd like to do this via TERR and ideally do not want to strsplit and convert all dates to strings and then do the same for my column and use some sort of 'TestID' in as.Character(pcMultiListBox)' etc. Also thought about breaking the string on comma and inputting into a list then iterating through it if 'TestID' is = iteratedDateIDElement but don't want to use a for-loop if possible.

Comment: when you input a list property into TERR you need to use an expression and $map(..), so it does turn into a string. Have you thought about simply creating a date filter rather than a document property, and limiting the input data table parameter by filter?

Comment: @GaiaPaolini thanks for the reply. Input parm to TERR is an expression (not doc prop) `'${pcMultiListBox}'` and when output from TERR to a doc prop and displayed in a text viz as a label it outputs:
     01/01/2022 00:00:00,01/09/2022 00:00:00

This is somewhat fine as my multilist doc prop contains date time; however, the time is not preserved here. If I can resolve that then within TERR I can strstrip on the comma, then lapply  as.POSIXct andformat to get a list of POSIXct timestamps, then flatten to a 1D list and ideally filter tbl in via TERR

ex: myTbl [ myTBL$"DT" %in% myDTList , ]

Comment: RStudio:

`# single string of date time separated by a comma
stringDT <- "01/01/2022 01:07:24,01/05/2022 00:00:00,01/09/2022 00:00:00"

# one-dimension (single element) list of stringDT
oneDimList <- as.list(strsplit(stringDT, split=","))
oneElementList

# convert one-dim to two-dim list
twoDimList <- as.list(oneDimList[[1]])
twoDimList

# convert items in list to as.POSIXct (datetime)
#as.POSIXct(twoDimList[[3]], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
twoDimListDT <- lapply(twoDimList, function(myElement) as.POSIXct(myElement, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))`

Comment: Results in this:

`> twoDimListDT
[[1]]
[1] "2022-01-01 01:07:24 CST"

[[2]]
[1] "2022-05-01 CDT"

[[3]]
[1] "2022-09-01 CDT"`

Comment: sorry your new comment mentions time which was not part of the original question, and now I am confused as to what the problem is and what the desired solution is. The RStudio snippet is not formatted and I don't understand whether the result is what you want or what you don't want